# Matlab frequency response

Tags: matlab, filters, discrete-signals

I'm trying to make a frequency response of that function:

[image: function]

in matlab a made this:

```
d=[1 -0.494 0.6404];
p=[1 1.58567330897 0.96];
[h,w] = freqz(p,d,40000);
z = abs(h);
plot(w/pi,z);
```

d and p i calculated.
The plot gives me this:
[image: plot]

but in book has that answer:
 [image: answer]

as you can see the peak of magnitude is 2 and not about 6.5. '-'
What am I doing wrong?
H2 has an abs 1 because it is a all pass filter.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct. Please note that your graph is in the range $0$ to $1$ while the graph in the text is in the output range of $-\pi$ to $+\pi$

There is some output scaling issue. But since you are getting the same curve, you are just messing some constants is all.

please try $\text{plot}(w,z)$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I thought that w/pi was for normalize like in ex 1 from freqz function documentation. I did what you said and i get this:
[image]

sorry about my english i'm from brazil.